# Target specific content with iframe

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to target specific content with an iframe? I'm going to give some fake code here because the url is behind a firewall.:

```
var container = sym.$("container");
var map = ' <iframe width="'+container.width()+'" height="'+container.height()+'"     frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.fakesite.com"></iframe>';
container.html(map);
```

What I want to do is to target someone's name, their phone number, and their email. This is content that my company owns, so it's not illegal or jerky or anything. We want the content that's already in the system be dynamically displayed.

These would be in different domains.

Comment: What do you mean, target content?

Comment: yes, I would know who the specific person is. It would be in the url, like http://fakesite.com/john_smith. This page would have a ton of info I didn't need. I just need John Smith's name, phone, and email.

Comment: By target content, I want just specific info to show up in the new page.

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe's URL is on the same domain as the original page, you can find the iframe with JS, access the `contentDocument` property, and extract whatever HTML you need.

Comment: It won't be in the same domain. It will be a different domain.

Comment: These would be different domains.

Comment: Then you would run into security problems from the browser. Is there any way you could set it up to be from the same domain?

Comment: if the page had an RSS feed, could I pull in the info that way?

Comment: Probably. JavaScript has XML parsing features, no problem, and if it's on the same domain, you can get it with AJAX.